# Combining two IF statements into one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

The following two IF functions work on their own but I want them in the same cell

```
=IF(AND(E4="female", C4=3),0,1)
=IF(AND(E4="male", C4>1.5, F4>3.5),0,1)
```

Comment: welcome at superuser. How would you like to combine them (what should be the outputs)? What have you tried so far and why that doesn't work (what is the error message / wrong output)?

Answer (score 1):

If the expected result of whole formula of the cell are two separate digits in one cell, you should do something like this:

```
=IF(AND(E4="female", C4=3),0,1)&" / "&IF( AND(E4="male", C4>1.5, F4>3.5),0,1)
```

Result will looks like: 0 / 1

If you want to check second condition only when first return "false", then try this:

```
=IF(AND(E4="female", C4=3),0,IF(AND(E4="male", C4>1.5, F4>3.5),0,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(OR(AND(E4="male", C4>1.5, F4>3.5),AND(E4="female", C4=3)),0,1)`

This will show `0` if either `AND(E4="male", C4>1.5, F4>3.5)` or `AND(E4="female", C4=3)` are met, otherwise it will show `1`.